# R - Número de veces que aparece seguido un valor y sus posiciones. Las repeticiones pueden aparecer más de una vez

Tags: array, r, repetidos

Tengo un vector con valores que se repiten de vez en cuando y quisiera sacar cuantas veces aparece un valor repetido y en que posiciones, el valor puede aparecer más veces. Con un ejemplo se verá más claro:
C(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,1,5,6,1,1)

Entonces, si nos fijamos en el valor 1, quiero sacar que 1 aparece seguido 3 veces en las posiciones 1,2 y 3, y 4 veces en las posiciones 10, 11, 12, 13 y 2 veces en las posiciones 15 y 16

Intentaré explicar mejor para que quiero los datos. Mi matriz tiene una columna con la hora en la que ocurre un evento, por ejemplo el evento 1, y lo que necesito es calcular cuanto dura dicho evento cada vez que se repite:

T-----------E
8:05------ 1
8:06------ 1
8:07------ 1
8:08------ 2
8:09------ 2
8:10------ 1
8:11------ 1
8:12 ------ 3
.
.
.
En este caso, el evento 1 ha durado 3 minutos una vez y 2 minutos otra vez. Mi idea es utilizar el índice inicial y final del evento para calcular el tiempo que dura el evento:
Duracion_1[1] = T[3]-T[1]
Duracion_1[2] = T[7]-T[6]

Y así construir el vector de las duraciones del evento 1.

Espero haberlo dejado más claro.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre una alternativa usando un data.frame. Creo que cumple con lo que necesitas, aunque no me termina de quedar claro qué estructura de datos necesitas como salida final.

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 6, 1, 1)     

data.frame(x = x, 
#Aquí defino grupos de valores iguales consecutivos. No importa que sean el mismo número, solo importa que sean consecutivos.
           grupo = cumsum(c(1, diff(x) != 0))) %>% 
#Genero unos número de índice que coinciden con el índice de x
  mutate(index = 1:n()) %>% 
#Agrupo para obtener luego el número de elementos en cada grupo
  group_by(grupo) %>% 
  mutate(largo = n())
```

Obtengo:

```
  # A tibble: 17 x 4
  # Groups:   grupo [7]
      x grupo index largo
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1     3
2     1     1     2     3
3     1     1     3     3
4     2     2     4     4
5     2     2     5     4
6     2     2     6     4
7     2     2     7     4
8     3     3     8     2
9     3     3     9     2
10    1     4    10     4
11    1     4    11     4
12    1     4    12     4
13    1     4    13     4
14    5     5    14     1
15    6     6    15     1
16    1     7    16     2
17    1     7    17     2
```

En las columnas están los datos que necesitas: el valor en `x`, el grupo de valores iguales consecutivos al que pertenece, el índice en el que lo encuentras en `x` y el tamaño de grupo. Puedes reordenar a gusto para hacer más simple la revisión.